# Accept any object as argument in function

Tags: typescript

### What I have

I have a method in a class which I want to accept any object as an argument but I don't want to use `any`, for this I use a `generic` and extend `object`.

```js
class MyClass {
  saveObject<T extends object>(object: T | null) {}
}
```

With this implementation, `@typescript-eslint/ban-types` rule complains with the following error:
`Don't use 'object' as a type. The 'object' type is currently hard to use see this issue(https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)). Consider using 'Record<string, unknown>' instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys.` ok, then I will listen to Eslint and do the following implementation:

```js
class MyClass {
  saveObject<T extends Record<string, unknown>>(object: T | null) {}
}
```

with the above implementation, the Eslint error disappears, so I try to execute the method with a **random object**:

```js
anyOtherMethodInMyCode(payment: IPaymentModel | null): void {
    // execute our method  
    this.saveObject(payment);
}
```

**But the typescript compiler throws a new error**:

```sh
TS2345: Argument of type 'IPaymentModel | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown> | null'.   
Type 'IPaymentModel' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, unknown>'. 
    Index signature is missing in type 'IPaymentModel'.
```

One option is to use `Type Assertion` in the argument passed to the method as follow:

```js
anyOtherMethodInMyCode(payment: IPaymentModel | null): void {
    // execute our method with Type Assertion  
    this.saveObject(payment as Record<string, unknown>);
}
```

With the above, TS compiler errors disappear but it is not optimal to have to do this(Type Assertion) in all places where the method is executed.

### What I want

I don't understand how to accept **any object** as an argument without having this kind of errors without the need to use `any`.

Comment: This really seems like a perfect use of `object`, despite what your linter is telling you.    I don't know if it matters that I'm the one who filed [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732) or not, but I certainly didn't intend ever to imply that `object` was useless.  If you don't actually care about indexing into it with keys, then #21732 doesn't apply.  I'd suggest disabling the rule, or at least suppressing the error in that one line.  I can write this up as an answer, but if it doesn't meet your needs for some reason, could you elaborate about why?

Comment: I want to know why it is a good case to use `object`, a detailed answer with some examples would help me to deactivate the rule in a safer way and to understand when to use `object` and when to use `Record<string, unknown>`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't completely agree with the premise of the default configuration of 
[typescript-eslint's `ban-types` rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) which says that

> Avoid the `object` type, as it is currently hard to use due to not being able to assert that keys exist.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#21732](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732).

As the person who filed the linked issue, I do understand that it is painful to try to use built-in type guarding to take a value of type `object` and do anything useful with its properties.  It would be great if this were fixed.  However, the type `object` represents "a non-primitive value in TypeScript" in a way that `Record<string, unknown>` does not.  And, as you've noticed, `Record<string, unknown>` has its own problems, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300).  TypeScript has lots of pitfalls and pain points, and a blanket recommendation against one in favor of another doesn't seem advisable to me.

--

For this particular use case, you can switch from `object` to `{[k: string]: any}` and not `{[k: string]: unknown}`.  If you make this change, it will be easier to process the value inside of `saveObject`:

```
saveObject(obj: Record<string, any> | null) {
  if (obj === null) {
    console.log("nothing to save");
    return;
  }
  if (obj.format === "json") {
    // do something
  }
}
```

(I've changed your example so that it is not generic; this may be important for your actual use case, but as a code example there's no point in making a function generic if that generic-ness isn't used anywhere. A function with type signature `<T extends U>(x: T)=>void` can very often be replaced with `(x: U)=>void` with no ill effects)

This increased ease of use is not really type safe, since having properties of type `any` are similar to turning off type checking.  But there is special casing in TypeScript which will allow any object to be assignable to `{[k: string]: any}` but not `{[k: string]: unknown}`.  The latter type prohibits any `interface` types without an explicit [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)), while the former is very similar to `object` and does not have this restriction (see [microsoft/TypeScript#41746](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41746#issuecomment-736833091)).

If that works for you (and you are not using linting to prohibit `any`), then you will find things working better:

```
anyOtherMethodInMyCode(payment: IPaymentModel | null): void {
  this.saveObject(payment); // okay
}
otherTests(): void {
  this.saveObject("not an object"); // error!
  this.saveObject(() => 3); // okay, a function is an object
}
```

---

I would still say that unless `object` gives you some specific problem inside the implementation of `saveObject()`, it is reasonable to disable the linter for that one line and use `object` instead.  It is more expressive of "any non-primitive" than `Record` is.  According to the linter, the supposed reason not to use `object` is that it is hard to use. That is true; but it's easy to *supply*, and if you would like to *call* `this.saveObject()` in more places than you would like to *implement*, I'd rather do one annoying thing inside the implementation and not many annoying things at each call site.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAU4E8C2FwCyA9gCYQA2yA3gFDLJwBcyAzmFKAOYDcdyARsxABXHP2i96CZvyJFyEOCF4BfGjQTk4LFsgJYAwlp3U+LOADcIAeX4ArCAjAAKIveYAlR0SgkAPGwcIJwANAwgWAB8yAA+yCLk5ACUpvT0wDDIrvbIALz58cKJKbRpaQhEICzyEAB05ESczgBEIERgABZcyGBErJYQzUmSZchQEGDCUMp89GplGVludrUwPjhwYHkFzXbVIEOpowD0x8gkfdV4nVyzyPP3fEpY1p3QBBMdpKgg+gakEGcAAdsHhwMwMKD8GBiGRKHEEslmBYiMASEd6DcWLVzFZbA4nMCoeBhnwHu0OtAACoQNgsZxJZGo9GlNJYnEDfGOFytdrhZDLblDbjIU7IaBQHwAQju7NxNns3OcDLy0QAzMNRWciABrbBhODIGDCEBOYCVZDAXRKAWKpxkmhqIA)