# How to define a Typescript "object" as a Record for all interface types

Tags: typescript

`object` type is discouraged from being used in TS and recommended to be replaced with `Record`. However, this following code has an error:

```
interface Pkg {
    name: string;
}

const doSomething = (obj: Record<string, unknown>): void => {

}

const p: Pkg = {
    name: 'test'
}

doSomething(p);
```

> Argument of type 'Pkg' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, unknown>'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'Pkg'.

How do I create a type "Record" here that supports raw JSON objects as well as an interface?

Comment: "`object` type is discouraged from being used in TS and recommended to be replaced with `Record`."  Your linter is doing that, not the TypeScript compiler.  Reconfigure your linter, maybe.  Or use `Record<string, any>` instead of `Record<string, unknown>` which is special-cased to work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603759/accept-any-object-as-argument-in-function

Comment: ```interface Pkg extends Record<string, string> {
     name: string;
   }```