# What is a good alternative to object and any?

Tags: typescript

The general advice in Typescript community seems to be against the use of `object` type.

I gather it is because of the following behavior:

Trying to access **any** property on an `object` gives a "property does not exist on type 'object'" error [1]

For the same reason, the popular linter - typescript-eslint - bans the use of object and instead recommends the use of `Record<string, unknown>` [2].

While I think `Record<string,any>` may have been a better choice; perhaps `unknown` was chosen in favour of `any` as `any` is essentially opting out of types.

But the issue with `unknown` is that, it too requires extra code in terms of type guards before anything can be done with them [3].

I think, there is a need for a better solution; something that is not as restrictive as `object` or `unknown` but at the same time sits well with popular linters.

Any ideas ?

I guess my specific question will be:

I want to keep typescript-eslint happy without resorting to `unknown` ... is it possible ?

Notes:

- [1] It may be possible to access properties under a type guard (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732). But I want to avoid the use of type guards for simplicity.
- [2] https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md#default-options
- [3] https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown

Comment: *But the issue with unknown is that, it too requires extra code in terms of type guards before anything can be done with them [3].* is exactly the point of TypeScript - to get you to explicitly check types before being sure of what type a particular variable holds. IMO, use `unknown` and be happy with boilerplate in exchange for safer code.

Comment: I really don't like the default ban on `object` because "hard to use" is subjective and situation dependent (generic constraints and conditional types like `T extends object` are perfectly fine).  But linters are not TypeScript and you should feel free to turn off that error unless it really helps you.  I'm somewhat inclined to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603759/accept-any-object-as-argument-in-function), unless you can articulate a relevant distinction (and edit the question to show that distinction)

Comment: @jcalz Absolutely; the linked question is what am asking too. So I guess, disabling the linter rule is the best option for now. However, I if the linter could be modified to specifically allow the use of `object` in function arguments; I would still consider the general ban a good thing to keep.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for the response; but the use of boilerplate is specifically what am trying to avoid.