# Intersection types with interfaces fails to throw TypeScript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, category-theory, union-types

By mixing TypeScript types with interfaces in an intersection, I seem to loose the stricter behaviour of interfaces in my code. I want to be able to compose types using intersections (such that I can narrow down a type in specific instances), but I want to be able to keep the exactness of interfaces.

Take this code:

```js
type Vehicle = {
  name: string
  properties: Record<string, unknown>
}

interface CarProperties {
  electric?: boolean
}

type Car = Vehicle & {
  name: 'car'
  properties: CarProperties
}

const car: Car = {
  name: 'car',
  properties: {
    electric: false,
    someOther: 'bs' // <= I want this to throw a TS Error
  }
}
```

As the `CarProperties` is an interface, I would expect it to disallow the inclusion of the `someOther` key.

Why is this not the case? And how else would one go about achieving the same thing?

Comment: please let me know what do you think about this approach: https://tsplay.dev/w6XPvm . Please take a look at the last test case, I'm not sure how do you want to handle it

Comment: @captain-yossarian I much prefer the approach to first answer as it ___is___ more expressive, but I do somewhat take issue with your "drawback" case. It would be nice to have my cake and eat it by throwing a TS error in that scenario.

Comment: FYI, it is very easy to handle it with extra function

Comment: how about this https://tsplay.dev/WPxRzW ? Feel free to get rid of `| never`. If you want to disallow `properties` to be an empty object you should make `electric` property a required. If it does not meet your expectations, please provide test cases with expected behavior

Comment: Strict test cases are hard to supply here as one of my aims is clearly subjective: to make composable types declarative in the places where I (and others) need to see how the type is structured. In regards to your last attempt, aside from the fact that `| never` adds extra boilerplate, I also get linting errors when using `object` advising me against using it.

Comment: feel free to get rid of `| never`, it is redundant. As for using `object` , I'm aware about this linting rule. In most cases it is preferred to use `Record<string, unknown>` but in your particular case I believe using `object` is justified. But it is only my opinion

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks for your help. Feel free to promote this to an answer and I will upvote as I have done with t.animal's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239356/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-shennan).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the intersection type `Car`. This leads to `properties` of car being a `Record<string, unknown> & CarProperties` and thus allows string keys.

To achieve what you want, you can add a generic to your Vehicle type:

```
type Vehicle<T extends object> = {
  name: string
  properties: T
}

type GenericVehicle = Vehicle<Record<string, unknown>>;

interface CarProperties {
  electric?: boolean
}

interface Car extends Vehicle<CarProperties> {
  name: 'car'
}
```

PS: I noticed you call this a "union type", [which it is not](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-intersection-types/). Intersection types share the properties of the intersected types, whereas union types can be either of the unionized types.

Comment: Interesting that a union allows for the less-specific type to remain as a fallback. I didn't know that. The reason I wanted to avoid generics is they're not very declarative, as they don't show how they're being used in the place you express them. For me to understand what an argument in a generic was, I would have to go and look at the original definition of the type and see how it was used. With the code in my example, I can see exactly how the union effects my original type, right where I declare it.

Comment: In this case you are allowed to use `Vehicle<[]>`. I think it should be taken into account

Comment: @t.animal yes it appears I was meaning intersection rather than union. Perhaps why I had trouble googling my problem. Have changed the question to reflect the correct term. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `electric` property a required one and use `object` type instead of `Record<string, unknown>`.

```js
type Vehicle = {
    name: string
    properties: object, // <---- change
}

type CarProperties = {
    electric: boolean // is required now
}

type Car = Vehicle & {
    name: 'car'
    properties: CarProperties
}


// ok
const car2: Car = {
    name: 'car',
    properties: {
        electric: false,
    }
}

// expected error
const car4: Car = {
    name: 'car',
    properties: []
}

// expected error
const car5: Car = {
    name: 'car',
}

// error
const car3: Car = {
    name: 'car',
    properties: {}
}

// error
const car: Car = {
    name: 'car',
    properties: {
        electric: false,
        someOther: 'bs' // error
    }
}
```

I know, using `object` type is controversial a bit, because of [this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/ban-types.md) rule, but you can find more information about pros and cons in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603759/accept-any-object-as-argument-in-function) answer.

If you have more variants of `Vehicle`, not only one `Car`, you may want to remove `properties` from `Vehicle` type and create a discriminated union of allowed `Vehicles`. It is only my guess, since I'm not aware of any other requirements.

It is also worth knowing about [excess-property-checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). It will disallow you to provide any other extra properties for literal argument.

If you put all your requirements and test cases into your question I believe you will get what you are looking for